# Warnings while using a plugin and static library in a cocoa project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a scenario where I need to use a plugin as well as a static library into my xcode project. The plugin will be dynamically loaded into the system. Now, the static library is also getting used in creation of the plugin.

While executing my project I am getting a warning saying :

Class A is getting referenced from /staticLibraryPath and plugin. One of them will be used.

Please let me know, how to resolve the warning or a better way of implementing the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

#### The issue is a name class of the two ClassA types found in both plugin and library

I assume you have control over the source of either plugin / library.

.. rename Class A in one instance to make the names not clash -- I don't think there is another way to get rid of the warning/error

Comment: Note that if they're both using the same implementation of the static lib that the main app could export the entry points of the static lib used by the plugin and the plugin could then link against the app.

Comment: a static lib normally doesn't have an entry point -- why would a lib (static/dynamic) have a main method